# Connection NAO with RoboEarth

Tags: ros, knowrob, nao, roboearth, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

my name is Florian from the HAW Hamburg. I am still writing my Masterthesis about knowledge sharing for robots....especially for the NAO robot from Aldebaran robotics.
So...my thesis deals with the connection between RoboEarth and NAO. The target is, that serveral NAO`s can exchange executable action recipes among eachother to improve their learning mechanism.
Also...i am now developing an interface between NAO and RoboEarth via the ROS-Middleware.
My problem is that, i can´t translate any CRAM-action-recipes into physical low-level routines from the NAO robot. So i can´t execute the CRAM-action-receipe on the NAO.
In the paper  "RoboEarth Action Recipe Execution" i have read, that i can access the robot hardware routines over process modules and actionlib libary from ROS.
So....what should i do to handle that problem...to execute CRAM-action recipes on the NAO robot?
Must i implement my own process modules for the NAO?

Thanks :)

Kind regards

Florian Johannßen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51651/connection-nao-with-roboearth/) by [FlorianJo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3921/florianjo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) on 2013-01-08**:
If you're using NAO robots in depth and there aren't many people who can help, you might contact the creators at Aldebaran robotics.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-01-22**:
By the way, it normally pays off to tag your question with the names of related ROS stacks or other subjects since several people (like me) get notified by mail whenever a question on a related topic is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are different ways to execute action recipes on other platforms. The CRAM system is preferred for complex object manipulation tasks and well-integrated with KnowRob and the RoboEarth system. It however has quite a steep learning curve, and getting into it may be difficult in the beginning.

Depending on which kinds of tasks you would like to execute, it may be an option to write a converter that reads action recipes and puts them into whatever execution engine you have. In that case, you could still use the other components of RoboEarth (exchange of action descriptions, object models, environment maps, perception interfaces). If you elaborate a bit more on what your goals are, we may be able to give some more pointers how to start.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1